# Diffeomorphism groups of h-cobordant manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Do we have specific examples of h-cobordant smooth manifolds $M$ and $M'$ such that $\operatorname{BDiff}(M) \not \simeq \operatorname{BDiff}(M')$? Perhaps something can be said in terms of K-theory by analyzing bundles of h-cobordisms?

In fact, if it helps to stabilize, I would be happy to know that $\operatorname{BDiff}_{\partial}(M \times I) \not \simeq \operatorname{BDiff}_{\partial}(M’ \times I)$.

Comment: So should you look at dimensions 3 and 4?

Comment: @user51223 Preferably, in dimensions where s-cobordism applies.

Comment: I would look at $L(7,1) \times S^4$ and $L(7,2) \times S^4$ (or maybe a higher-dimensional version thereof). These are h-cobordant but not diffeomorphic by a result of Milnor, and their diffeomorphisms seem pretty accessible through surgery theory and pseudoisotopy theory.

Comment: It seems worth thinking first about the analogous (easier) question for block-diffeomorphisms.

Comment: I suspect that the theorem of [Longoni-Salvatore](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401075) is relevant. Homotopy equivalent lens spaces do not have homotopy equivalent configuration spaces ($X^2-\Delta$); but the group of homeomorphisms of $X$ acts on the configuration space.

Answer (score 6):

This is regarding your second question.

In dimensions $\geq 5$, where the $s$-cobordism theorem applies, $h$-cobordisms are invertible in the following sense: if $W : M \leadsto M'$ is an $h$-cobordism, then there exists an $h$-cobordism $W' : M' \leadsto M$ such that $W' \circ W \cong M \times [0,1]$, and $W \circ W' \cong M' \times [0,1]$. In other words, $W$ embeds into $M \times [0,1]$ relative to $M \times \{0\}$ and so on. This can be used to obtain maps
$$B\mathrm{Diff}_\partial(M \times [0,1]) \overset{W \circ -}\to B\mathrm{Diff}_\partial(W) \overset{W' \circ -}\to B\mathrm{Diff}_\partial(W' \circ W) \cong B\mathrm{Diff}_\partial(M \times [0,1])$$
which are homotopy inverses to each other. But similarly
$$B\mathrm{Diff}_\partial(M' \times [0,1]) \overset{- \circ W}\to B\mathrm{Diff}_\partial(W) \overset{- \circ W'}\to B\mathrm{Diff}_\partial(W \circ W') \cong B\mathrm{Diff}_\partial(M' \times [0,1])$$
are homotopy inverses, and so
$$B\mathrm{Diff}_\partial(M \times [0,1]) \simeq B\mathrm{Diff}_\partial(W) \simeq B\mathrm{Diff}_\partial(M' \times [0,1]).$$

In the comments @archipelago suggests that one should think about the case of block diffeomorphisms. Consider the (semi-simplicial) group $\widetilde{\mathrm{Diff}}(W)$ of block diffeomorphisms of $W$ which do not fix the boundaries pointwise but preserve each of the two boundary components setwise. There are maps
$$B\widetilde{\mathrm{Diff}}(M) \leftarrow B\widetilde{\mathrm{Diff}}(W) \to B\widetilde{\mathrm{Diff}}(M') \tag{1}$$
given by restriction, whose fibres are $B\widetilde{\mathrm{Diff}}_M(W)$ and $B\widetilde{\mathrm{Diff}}_{M'}(W)$. Now by the same kind of reasoning as above (namely gluing on $W'$) we have
$$B\widetilde{\mathrm{Diff}}_M(W) \simeq B\widetilde{\mathrm{Diff}}_{M'}(M' \times [0,1])$$
but this is just the (classifying space of the) space of block concordances of $M'$, and spaces of *block* concordances are contractible by a kind of Alexander trick. Thus the two maps in (1) are equivalences, so indeed
$$B\widetilde{\mathrm{Diff}}_\partial(M) \simeq B\widetilde{\mathrm{Diff}}_\partial(M').$$

(I don't know the answer to your original question about $B{\mathrm{Diff}}_\partial(M) \overset{?}\simeq B{\mathrm{Diff}}_\partial(M')$, but it seems quite interesting and the above suggests also considering the related question about concordances of $M$ versus those of $M'$.)

EDIT:
My argument in the case of block diffeomorphisms is slightly fallacious. The fibres of the maps in (1) need not be connected, as diffeomorphisms of $M$ (or $M'$) need not extend over $W$. However, it is true that each path-component of these fibres is contractible, as I said, because it can be identified with a space of block-concordances. The conclusion of the argument is thus that $B\widetilde{\mathrm{Diff}}(M)$ and $B\widetilde{\mathrm{Diff}}(M')$ have a common covering space, so e.g. have equivalent universal covers. Remarkably, their fundamental groups can be different: this has been proved by Samuel Muñoz Echániz, and will appear in his forthcoming PhD thesis.

Comment: In the pseudoisotopy stable range $\widetilde{\mathrm{Diff}}_\partial(M)/\mathrm{Diff}_\partial(M)$ is given by the $\mathbb{Z}/2$-orbits of the Whitehead spectrum of $M$, so going from $\widetilde{\mathrm{Diff}}$ to $\mathrm{Diff}$ is in a range only a question of extensions. This ought to be doable away from the prime 2 using Burghelea-Lashof. See Section 1.5 of https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0012101 for related results in the topological setting.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I believe the embedding tower even predicts $B\mathrm{Diff}_\partial(M \times [0,1]) \simeq B\mathrm{Diff}_\partial(M' \times [0,1])$ , but I'm surprised it is accurate since it is codimension 0.

Comment: @skupers Since the manifold is not simply connected, isn't the stable range empty?

Comment: No, it's at least about $\dim/3$ whatever the fundamental group. See Theorem 1.3.4 of the link.